# Issue about using prebuilt third library inAndroid.bp

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, android-build

I have a library called **libhelloworld.so** built by NDK. Then I push it into **/vendor/my/lib** in ASOP and write a Android.bp in **/vendor/my/** to integrate it:

```
cc_prebuilt_library_shared {
    name: "libhelloworld",
    vendor: true,
    srcs: ["lib/libhelloworld.so"],
}
```

**mmm vendor/my/**, this library will be generated into **out/target/product/balabala/vendor/lib64/**.

I write a native app to invoke this library:

```
cc_binary {
    name: "test_helloworld",
    vendor: true,
    srcs: [
        "test_helloworld.cpp",
    ],
    shared_libs: [
        "liblog",
        "libhelloworld",
    ],
}
```

**mmm it**, the **test_helloworld** will be generated into **out/target/product/balabala/vendor/bin/**.

However, when I use **objdump -p test_helloworld**, it shows below:
**NEEDED vendor/my/lib/libhelloworld.so** which is not what I expect:
**NEEDED libhelloworld.so**.

Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 1):

The **libhelloworld.so** has no **SONAME** in its ELF. Fix this by adding **-Wl,-soname,libhelloword.so**